# mod_rewrite: web page has a redirect loop

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I'm trying to have a parameter that comes just after he hostname, as in:

www.domain.com/parameter

For this reason, I've set the following rewriteRule, for two parameter values that I'd like to operate with:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|pt)$ /index.php?language=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Works fine! Although, I need to create a new rule, to redirect any request without one the parameters listed.

For that reason, I thought this would work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(en|pt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pt/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But unfortunately is showing a redirect loop.

I've been getting:

```
http://hostname/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt/pt//
```

Any tips on how to fix this are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

That's because *directories* are not *regular files*.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html (no HTML DOM `id` for the snippet! closest one is an unrelated `LA-U`, even what should have been an  `id="LA-F"` is missing!)

> You can perform various file attribute tests:
>
> ```
> '-d' (is directory)
> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
> '-f' (is regular file)
> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.
> ```

Provided the rest of your config is correct (I'm not sure adding a trailing slash is a good idea), you should add an extra condition for `!-d`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(en|pt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pt/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

---

Also, consider switching to nginx!  Not only does it have a clearer syntax more geared towards common use, but it also has direct links to relevant documentation, like so -- http://nginx.org/r/if.

> checking of a file, directory, or symbolic link existence with the “-e” and “!-e” operators;

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I really appreciate it. I've tried but without succcess. It's not redirecting it seems ( http://pastie.org/10475373 ). I'm expecting to get the http://domain.com/parameter (default), instead I get http://domain.com the request I've sent originally. @cnst

Comment: @punkbit, I don't know how that would be possible!  (Perhaps you have to provide more details, or maybe ask a new question.)

Answer (score 0):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` is the URI path just following hostname, therefore, it starts with the forward slash: `/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|pt)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /pt/$0/ [R=301,L]
```